# how to add multiple bind multiple classes to element with multiple booleans using v-bind:class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I am trying to assign classes into an element depending on whether or not a `boolean` is true. I was able to do this using `v-bind:class` for some classes. However now I want to do this again for another `boolean` at the same time. This is for a to-do list app.

my current code:

```html
<div
  v-bind:class="[task.checked ? '!bg-gray-800 text-gray-600 line-through' : 'none']"
  v-bind:class="[task.checked ? '!bg-gray-800 text-gray-600 line-through' : 'none']"
  class="tasks_container grid grid-cols-10"
  v-for="task in tasks"
>
  <!-- task for loop -->
</div>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    note_text: ' ',
    tasks: [
      {
        text: 'hello',
        checked: false,
        selected: true
      },
      {
        text: 'world',
        checked: false,
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  };
},
```

I tried doing **:**

```html
<div
  v-bind:class="[task.checked ? '!bg-gray-800 text-gray-600 line-through' : 'none']"
  v-bind:class="[task.selected ? '!bg-gray-100' : 'none']"
  class="tasks_container grid grid-cols-10"
  v-for="task in tasks"
>
  <!-- task for loop -->
</div>
```

this didn't work because you cant have multiple `v-bind:class`

I also tried **:**

```html
<div
  v-bind:class="[task.checked?'!bg-gray-800 text-gray-600 line-through':'none'], ['task.selected? !bg-gray-100':'none']"
  v-for="task in tasks"
>
  <!-- task for loop -->
</div>
```

that didn't work but I forget what is said for why. I'm sorry if my code has weird please let me know how I can fix that I'm new to stackoverflow and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into the answer I added ? I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 2):

Vue [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes) has an example of binding classes using multiple data properties.  Yours can be written like this:

```html
<div
  :class="{ '!bg-gray-800 text-gray-600 line-through': task.checked, '!bg-gray-100': task.selected }"
  v-for="task in tasks"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this requirement, You can pass an object to `v-bind:class` directive to dynamically toggle the classes.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [
        {
          text: 'hello',
          checked: true,
          selected: true
        },
        {
          text: 'world',
          checked: false,
          selected: true
        }
      ]
    };
  }
})
```

```css
.text-gray-600 {
 color: gray;
}
.line-through {
  text-decoration: line-through; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div
       v-for="(task, index) in tasks"
       :key="index"
       :class="{ '!bg-gray-800 text-gray-600 line-through': task.checked, '!bg-gray-100': task.selected }"
       >
    {{ task.text }}
  </div>
</div>
```